# Delphi Firemonkey TLayout mousedown not firing

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

I am creating a button array in Firemonkey and each of the buttons are created by loading a style from a resource.

```
FButtons[r,c] := TLayout( TStyleManager.LoadFromResource(HInstance, BUTTON_STYLE, RT_RCDATA) );
FButtons[r,c].Parent := Self;
FButtons[r,c].Stored := false;
FButtons[r,c].HitTest := true;
FButtons[r,c].OnMouseDown := OnButtonMouseDown;
```

The contents of the resource is just copied from a TButton (dark style).

The problem I am having is that the button does not animate a pressed state. So I am trying to capture the OnMouseDown event to fire the "IsPressed" animation but the OnMouseDown is never triggered. 
Any ideas why OnMouseDown is not happening?

Thanks in advance.
Martin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dont know why but setting

```
Locked := true
```

fixed my problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using custom FM style, then ensure HitTest property of style's elements (containers probably) is set to False.
If HitTest is True the style itself will "swallow" the event.

You may find more information here:

- ["Beware the HitTest"](http://monkeystyler.com/blog/entry/10-things-every-firemonkey-developer-should-know-about-styles)
- ["Glyphs on buttons"](http://blog.analogmachine.org/2011/09/04/useful-tips-for-firemonkey-and-delphi-xe2/)

Comment: Yes, I have made sure that HitTest is not true on any descending objects.

Comment: Without loading the style does OnMouseDown fire?